# How can i secure client_id value in auth_config.json while using Auth0 for single page web application

Tags: web-applications, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, auth0, google-authentication

I am trying to use Auth0 for single page web application , as per document we have to store domain and client_id in auth_config.json file with JS files. As per document it is mentioned that client_id is public , so it is safe to but it with web files.  What can be done, to secure client_id and still use it in single page web app. Basically i do not want client_id to be access by anyone by inspecting UI page and then misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

The client ID is not a secret and is publicly visible in the URL when users click to login using Auth0. So even if you try to hide it in your code, it will still be exposed when users login with Auth0.

There is a client secret key that needs to be hidden at all times but the client id does not